# Certain faces will not line up with vertices when using subdivision modifier

Tags: modeling, modifiers, vertices, subdivision-surface

So I am creating a body, and I have applied the mirror and subdivision modifier, However, the lower faces meet the vertices whereas the upper faces do not, Why is this happening?

This is an image of the issue:
[image: Picture Showing Problem]

I extruded the part that works correctly but why is the chest area like that, Is there some modifier that i have to add. I am quite new to blender so this is very confusing.

Comment: You may have duplicate vertices. Try to select all vertices, then "Merge by Distance"